# What is the easiest way to pick portions of a string based on a template in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split

I'm trying to take values from this string:

```
-webkit-gradient(linear, right top, left top, color-stop(0, #FF7417),  color-stop(1, #82A8FF))
```

and convert it to other formats (-moz,-o-,-webkit-linear etc). Currently I'm doing this by splitting the string (using '(' , ',' etc) and then re-arranging the pieces into the new format. Is there an easy way to do this ?

Note: I don't need a way to convert between various gradient formats. I just need a generic way to pick required portions of a string based on a predefined template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo should capture each set with a regular expression, For example 
`/color-stop\(0,.+?\)/` should get you the first color-stop part. Then you just make a new string with each result:

```
"-webkit-gradient" + color + linear + righttop + etc;
```

[Simple tutorial about regexes and javascript](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/re.shtml)

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little more about the regular expression you have used.. also does this match all the colorstops and give me an array at end ?

Comment: It's not that easy, you have o make a regex for each thing you want to capture, they are not magical, i'll search a tut for this.

Comment: I've added a link to a tutorial, you should also search for a regex tool like Regex Coach for windows, it's free and learning is easier that way.